# Equivalent function "evalclusters" of MATLAB in julia

Tags: matlab, julia

I am translating my code in MATLAB regarding kmeans algorithm into julia.
According to my code of MATLAB,

```
  evaluation = evalclusters(W0,"kmeans","gap","KList",1:max_K);
  loc = evaluation.OptimalK;
  idx = evaluation.OptimalY;
```

this is used for finding optimal **K**. (I found it in MATLAB help website)

I am a just newbie of julia, so I am not aware of it.
But as far as I know, I think there is no one-to-one corresponding function of "evalcluster" in julia.

How can I deal with this problem?

(I read this [Julia official documentation](https://juliastats.org/Clustering.jl/dev/kmeans.html), but I could not find anything about evaluation of kmeans algorithm using "gap evaluation".)

Comment: Couldn't find an implementation, but maybe it could be a good contribution opportunity. Source code for the gap statistic in R can be found here: https://github.com/echen/gap-statistic/blob/master/gap-statistic.R (sorry for the less than useful answer)

Comment: If you want people to help you further, please include the evalcluster function in your post or a link to it

Comment: @TinoD `evalcluster` is a standard Matlab function. The question code is Matlab code

Comment: @DanGetz nice, then please post a link to it.

Comment: @TinoD Here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/evalclusters.html (that was a difficult click on first link google away)

Answer (score 0):

Like DanGetz, I couldn't find any implementation of the gap method but I think you can use any of the other methods implemented in Julia to find the optimal K. As, an example I used the Davies-Bouldin method. Review the clustering_quality.jl example [1](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Clustering.jl/blob/master/examples/clustering_quality.jl) from Clustering.jl package to find the most suitable one for your data set.

```
using Clustering
# test data with 3 clusters
W0 = hcat([4., 5.] .+ 0.4 * randn(2, 10),
         [9., -5.] .+ 0.4 * randn(2, 5),
         [-4., -9.] .+ 1 * randn(2, 5))
max_k = 5 

clusterings = kmeans.(Ref(W0), 2:max_k) # Works with a minimum of 2 clusters
loc = findmin(clustering_quality.(Ref(W0), clusterings, quality_index = 
      :davies_bouldin))[2] + 1
idx = clusterings[loc].assignments
```